# Spring MVC return simple text instead of JSON while using Ajax Call

Tags: java, jquery, json, ajax, spring

This is my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'configuration/activePlatform/',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function(data){
            console.log("getActivePlatform ACK");
            $('#activePlatform').append(data);
        },      
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
        alert(err.Message);
        }
    });
```

The response from this call is 200 OK.

I'm getting a clear text as the respone, the error msg is "Unexpected token s"

This is my server side code:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/configuration")
public class configuration {

    @Autowired
    public CommonConfigurations configurations;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/activePlatform", method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public @ResponseBody
    String activePlatform() throws Exception {

        return configurations.activePlatform;
    }
}
```

What did i do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `dispatcher-servlet.xml` You will need to configure viewName “`jsonTemplate`” as bean of type `MappingJackson2JsonView`. And you will need to configure view resolver of type `BeanNameViewResolver`. This way viewName “`jsonTemplate`” will be matched with `MappingJackson2JsonView` and parsed JSON response will be returned to client.

```
 <mvc:annotation-driven/>  
 <bean name="viewResolver"  
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver"/>  
 <bean name="jsonTemplate"  
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView"/>
```

**Important :-**

you need to have below jar in your classpath

- jackson-annotations-2.6.0.jar
- jackson-core-2.6.0.jar
- jackson-databind-2.6.0.jar

I found this [link](http://www.tutorialsdesk.com/2016/01/spring-rest-hello-world-json-tutorial.html) useful.

Comment: The problem is that this is working only when i return a class object for an example CommonConfigurations , when i return a string i get it as plain text and not in json format

Comment: i want to return the value of - "Sandbox"  or "Production" as string in JSON format.

Comment: you can format string value to json like --  return "[{\"ServerType\":\"Production\"}]";

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/serverType")
 public String getServerType(){  

  return "[{\"ServerType\":\"Production\"}]";  
 }

Comment: this will return you result as [{"ServerType":"Production"}]

Answer (score 0):

You can return the entire `configurations` object from controller method and call `data.activePlatform` in your ajax callback assuming your configurations object is not too big to say you are carrying too much unnecessary data across the layers.